how to eliminate websocket connection error in chrome extension
I am connecting to websocket server at localhost from my chrome extension (v3). My extension works with or without local application running. When my application is not running, websocket connection in extension fails and there is an error displayed in extension summary:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9999/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have already put socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9999/ws"); in try catch block, but it doesn't help.
Is there any way to eleminate the warning which might confuse user?
